# React-select component value not updating.

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Just wondering what I am doing wrong here. When I select a value out of the list the component input field is not being filled in with the value.

```
class Search extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: 'order_select_field',
        placeholder: "Make a selection",
    }
}

componentWillMount () {
    fetch('http://apirequest.com')
        .then( function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(json) {
            this.setState({options: json});
        }.bind(this))
    }

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                name={this.state.name}
                options={this.state.options}
                placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: do not use ajax requests on `componentWillMount`! by the way this method is basically as the contructor. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: What library are you using for the Select component?

Comment: @JulianSoro I am using react-select

Comment: I'm using react-select also and have the same problem although my code is slightly different.

Answer (score 11):

Your main issue is your handleChange method doesn't set the value

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    value: event.target.value
  })
}
```

With a vanilla `<select>` component, the onChange event would have a DOMElement reference at `event.target`, and react provides the `value` prop on the DOM element do you can use it to update your state. You're 3rd-party `<Select>` component might have a different event signature or expectation.

Also, since I don't know what library you're using, I've provided the state key which tracks your value as "yourSelectKey", but you can replace this with the correct key. If it's a nested property (part of an object), you may have to add the spread operator so that the other values get copied over as well.

And you need to add the onChange event handler to your select component. I recommend you follow the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) instead of using that library.

```
<select
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}>
  name={this.state.name}>

    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>

</select>
```

**Other issues you're facing:**

- You need to bind `handleChange` to your object instance. You can either do this in the constructor with a line `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` or by declaring `handleChange` as an instance variable, as I have done above.
- as the commenter said, you should avoid doing the fetch call in componentWillMount, but should use componentDidMount. This is a common mistake for beginners.

Comment: @Jasonca1 I've modified this answer to use a standard DOMElement for `<select>`, and I think that the library you're using is not necessary.

Comment: I think this answer is heading you down the wrong path.  Select-react wants you to handle things a certain way.  I've got a similar problem with that same component, and I can see this is only going to muck things up.